# Scala IDEA and activator build the same project separately

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework-2.0

I'm using IntellIj IDEA + scala + play2 plugins to develop my Play! application.

I enabled 'Auto make' option on IDEA and after the build is finished in IDEA, and when I try to run the application in activator console, it does the another build process on the console.

How can I make these two environment to share the build environment?